# Enable fullscreen in Blueimp gallery for bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gallery, fullscreen, blueimp

how do I enable the "fullscreen mode" of Blueimp gallery for bootstrap3, it is working now, but only in "window mode", and I would like to use it in full screen, so that images use the full width and height on desktop/tablet/phone screen.

This is what I am talking about:

http://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `fullScreen` to `true` in the gallery's option hash. Notice it is case-sensitive. If you use the script from the website, change the line:

```
<script>
    ...
    options = {index: link, event: event, fullScreen: true},
    ...
</script>
```

At least that worked for me. When I decided to use the **jQuery** version of the plug-in and added the fullscreen option as a data-tag, I ran into another problem: Rails converted the tag `fullScreen` to lowercase, and then it was not recognised by the plug-in. I had to add a line of javascript that set the option manually:

```
$('#blueimp-gallery').data( 'fullScreen', 'true' );
```

Now, it is working for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
$('#blueimp-gallery').data('fullScreen', 'true');
```

full example

```
<html><head>
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<![endif]-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
</head><body>

<div id="links" data-slideshow="100" class="modal-fullscreen">
    <a href="111.jpg" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-fullscreen">111</a>
    <a href="222.jpg" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-fullscreen">222</a>
</div>

<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
    <div class="slides"></div>    
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#blueimp-gallery').data('fullScreen', 'true');
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to enable it here:

```
var fullscreenOptions = {
    fullScreen: false
};
```

From the [Blueimp Gallery README](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/blob/master/README.md#fullscreen-options)